# How can I write query using groupby .net core 5.0

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, asp.net-core-5.0

I get this error:

> Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[berberApp.Models.ViewModel.AdminReservationviewModel]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[berberApp.Models.ViewModel.AdminReservationviewModel]' of method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.Int32,berberApp.Models.ViewModel.AdminReservationviewModel]] GroupBy[AdminReservationviewModel,Int32](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[berberApp.Models.ViewModel.AdminReservationviewModel], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[berberApp.Models.ViewModel.AdminReservationviewModel,System.Int32]])' (Parameter 'arg0')

controller.cs

```
t = (from reservation in c_.Reservations
     join times in c_.Times
          on reservation.TimeId equals times.TimeId
     join users in c_.Users 
          on reservation.EmployerId equals users.UserId
     orderby reservation.Date
     select new ReservationViewModel
                {
                    MeetingId = reservation.MeetingId,
                    UserName = users.UserName,
                    Date = reservation.Date,
                    Time = times.TimeName,
                    ToplamSure = reservation.ToplamSure,
                    ToplamTutar = reservation.ToplamTutar,
                    Service = (from m in c_.MultiReservations                                 
                               join s in c_.Services on m.ServiceId equals s.ServiceId
                               where reservation.MeetingId == m.MeetingId
                               select new AdminReservationviewModel
                                    {
                                        ServiceId = m.ServiceId,
                                        Operations = s.Operation,
                                    }).ToList()
                                  .GroupBy(s => s.ServiceId).ToList()
                     }).ToList();
```

ReservationViewModel.cs

```
    public int MeetingId { get; set; }
    public int MultiReservationId { get; set; }
    public int ServiceId { get; set; }
    public string Operations { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
    public int TimeId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    public List<IGrouping<int,AdminReservationviewModel>> Service { get; set; }
```

AdminReservationviewModel.cs

```
 public int ServiceId { get; set; }
 public string Operations { get; set; }
```

I want to list user's services in user's reservation's list with using `groupby` expression in a Linq query.

Comment: Usually, grouping isn't necessary if navigation properties are used. Try that first. Remove all joins and create navigation properties. After that, if you still need help, post the updated class model and the query you tried using that model.

Comment: There is more than one same data and i want to write only one. I can write with distinct but I got error. How can ı wirte only one data ?